# How do I find out whether an object's type is a subclass of IEnumerable<T> for any value type T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I need to validate an object to see whether it is null, a value type, or `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a value type.  So far I have:

```
if ((obj == null) ||
    (obj .GetType().IsValueType))
{
    valid = true;
}
else if (obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
{
     // TODO: check whether the generic parameter is a value type.
}
```

So I've found that the object is null, a value type, or `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`; how do I check whether that `T` is a value type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(edit - added value type bits)

You need to check all the interfaces it implements (note it could in theory implement `IEnumerable<T>` for multiple `T`):

```
foreach (Type interfaceType in obj.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
    if (interfaceType.IsGenericType
        && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        Type itemType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        if(!itemType.IsValueType) continue;
        Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable-of-" + itemType.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is GetInterfaces sufficiently recursive to mean you don't need to worry about going up the parent types?

Comment: You don't need no recursion. A class either implements an interface, or it doesn't. It's a flat list, regardless of how the interfaces themselves "inherit" each other.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do somethin with `GetGenericArguments` ?

Answer (score 0):

My generic contribution that checks if a given type (or its base classes) implements an interface of type T:

```
public static bool ImplementsInterface(this Type type, Type interfaceType)
{
    while (type != null && type != typeof(object))
    {
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(@interface => 
            @interface.IsGenericType
            && @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType))
        {
            return true;
        }

        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return false;
}
```