# Getting the type argument of an ICollection<T> implementing class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I am writing a little serialization library in .net. The goal is to have a replacement for XmlSerialize but easier to configure and without messing up the model with attributes.

The problem that I face is that I need the type of each  `ICollection<T>` I find during traversing the model.
The naive approach is this:

```
 var theType=myModel.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

But it does not help for classes that derive from `ICollection<T>` with a specific T.

```
public class MyClass:A,ICollection<B>{}
```

I tried getting the interface with reflection

```
  var iCollectionInterface =
  o.GetType().GetInterfaces()
     .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
     .Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
     .FirstOrDefault(i => i == typeof(ICollection<>));
```

but `iCollectionInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0]` is just `T`, not `B` because it describes only the definition of the interface and not the usage of it.

Any ideas? I also need it for `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` but that is basically the same problem and will have the same solution.

Thank you!

*Edit*

Thank you all, here is what I ended up with:

```
public static Type GetTypeParameter(object o, Type typeToSearch, int argumentNumber)
{
    return o.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
            .Where(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeToSearch)
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[argumentNumber])
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637987/how-do-i-find-out-whether-an-objects-type-is-a-subclass-of-ienumerablet-for-a?rq=1 shows you how to filter to the interface you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems you need to figure out how to filter the collection to only include ICollection. You can reach that goal by:

```
var iCollectionInterfaces =
      from i in o.GetType().GetInterfaces()
      where i.IsGenericType 
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IColection<>)
      select i;
```

You can then iterate over the collection and do whatever you need to with each type argument

```
//same type might implement ICollection<T> more than once
foreach(var collection in iCollectionInterfaces) {
     //More than one is invalid for ICollection<T>
    var T = collection.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    //do what ever you need
}
```

of course if you want to make it more generic. Ie to support interfaces/types with more than one type argument you need to remove the call to `Single` and replace with iteration of the type arguments

Comment: Thanx, just for completeness, one `.Where(i => i.IsGenericType)` helps preventing an error on `i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` if it is not a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need: [Type.GetGenericArguments Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) .

So, having

```
class MyDictionary: IDictionary<string, decimal>
{
    ...
}
```

Try this extension method:

```
public static Type[] GetClosingArguments<T>(this Type type)
{
    Type iType = typeof(T).GetInterfaces()
                          .FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                                     i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type);
    if (iType == null)
        return null;
    else
        return iType.GetGenericArguments();
}
```

like this

```
Type[] types = typeof(IDictionary<,>).GetClosingArguments<MyDictionary>();
if (types != null)
{
    foreach (Type t in types)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

or vice versa:

```
public static Type[] GetClosingArguments(this Type type, Type baseGenericType)
{
    Type iType = type.GetInterfaces()
                     .FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                               i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseGenericType);
    if (iType == null)
        return null;
    else
        return iType.GetGenericArguments();
}
```

that is called

```
Type[] types = typeof(MyDictionary).GetClosingArguments(typeof(IDictionary<,>));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it gives me the types. But my problem is more the filtering to `ICollection<>` implementations.

Comment: @Enton did you read your own question? There is nothing there about filtering.

Comment: My question was not "get all type parameters for all interfaces that are implemented" but "get the type parameter for the implementation of one specific interface"

Comment: @Enton I didn't feel the emphasis on filtering...well, sorry about that. Nevertheless, have a look at my suggestion. Now it's closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following call is the problem

```
.Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

You take the closed generic type with defined generic arguments, then you get its generic definition, which is open and only knows `T`. Maybe you will also need to change the `FirstOrDefault` call, I'm not sure if the closed type equals `ICollection<>`